# Construct a preconditioner for the linear system $Ax = b$ from a different matrix

Tags: linear-solver, petsc, preconditioning

When I use PETSc to solve my linear systems, I always use the subroutine

```
PetscErrorCode  KSPSetOperators(KSP ksp,Mat Amat,Mat Pmat)
```

where `Amat` refers to the matrix that defines my linear system and `Pmat` is the Matrix used in constructing the preconditioner.

I am not sure in which scenarios it would be advisable to use another matrix than $A$ or `Amat` to construct the preconditioner, i.e. to use a preconditioner from another (probably related) linear system.

**EDIT**
Taking a look at the PETSc Manual, one possible occasion in which the matrices `Amat` and `Pmat` differ is

> when a preconditioning matrix is obtained from a lower order method
>   than that employed to form the linear system matrix.

Comment: A preconditioner doesn't have to be an explicit matrix (see tutorial parabolic.c for SSOR preconditioner), in which case you can set it to call your own function to multiply it by a vector. Also, $A$ and $P$ *should* always differ, a preconditioner (depending on convention) is an approximation to the inverse $A^{-1}$, not the matrix itself (so you solve $PAx=Pb$, so multiplication by $P$ should be cheap). I don't really understand this question: why *wouldn't* you want the freedom to specify your own arbitrary preconditioner?

Comment: @Kirill I'm sorry if my question led to confusion. In fact `Pmat` is not equal to $P$, instead it is an approximate of $\tilde{A}$ of $A$ that is used to "construct" the preconditioner $P$.

Comment: I have no direct experience here, I looked at lines 1055-1077 of http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/src/tao/pde_constrained/examples/tutorials/parabolic.c.html and it uses KSPSetOperators to set its own preconditioner. Also, not all preconditioners are constructed directly from the matrix. They could come from a simpler equivalent system, mathematical considerations, or from somewhere else entirely, like FFT, wavelet transform. But maybe that's not relevant to KSPSetOperators, I don't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since nobody is stepping up to answer this question, let me point to a paper that contains an example of why one would want to do this: http://www.math.tamu.edu/~bangerth/publications.html#publications/reviewed-34 (publication 34, Kronbichler et al.). In fact, there are multiple examples in this paper:

- We precondition $\begin{pmatrix}A &B \\ B^T & 0\end{pmatrix}$ by a block triangular matrix.
- We precondition $A$ by one V-cycle based not on $A$ but based on an approximation $\tilde A$ that is simpler and emptier.
- We approximate the exact $S^{-1}$ in the block preconditioner by the application of a mass matrix.

Complex applications quite frequently play with these things. You just don't ever see them if you just solve simple, scalar problems :-)